# Ethereum sidechains

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

- I have just started learning blockchain development
- I have created an ethereum sidechain, which is running on docker containers in my local machine.
- I have previously used solidity to write smart contracts and deploy them on the testnet using truffle, or by getting the provider from infura.

**Note**: wherein each container acts as a node.

But how do I do the same thing for my private chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure truffle to point to your testnet. The [truffle config docs](https://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration) describe how to do this in detail. Essentially you want to put the following in your truffle.js file:

```
networks: {
    test: {
        host: "<ip address of one of your docker containers>",
        port: <port number your container is listening on>,
        network_id: "*"  // match any network id
    }
}
```